# Difference in results between "preference" and "search_type" on _search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get consistent scoring for ElasticSearch results and I need to overcome the problem described here in the first section: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/consistent-scoring.html

I believe that the answer might be to use a preference, like _search?preference=_only_local or preference=xyzabc123. But, I'm not sure.  I get a different score when I use _search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch and it seems like this search_type would always give the most consistent scoring.  However, since the results are different from the search with the preference parameter, I'm not sure - the order of the results is different because the top result with the preference-style search gets a lower score when I do the search_type-style search (which means that other docs are getting a better score now).

The preference result looks like this:

```
  "took" : 13,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1886,
    "max_score" : 4.765499,
    "hits" : ...
```

The search_type result looks like this:

```
  "took" : 8,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1886,
    "max_score" : 4.68168,
    "hits" : ...
```

I'm hesitant about the dfs_query_then_fetch because there's a note that says it's not needed in production, but I need something that's going to return the same results to a query done twice, or more, in a row and not a different result set each time (actually, running without either of these parameters, the _search returns two different result sets and flip-flops back and forth between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: You must use `preference` for consistency in results across requests for same query and optionally, `search_type` as well for potentially greater accuracy.

I think the doc you referenced has a lot of the information you need to assist you with understanding the `search_type` and the `preference` parameters.  In addition to those, these might help:

- [Search Type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-type)
- [Preference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-preference)

Based on some of the things you already tried, it seems like you may have already found and relied on these.

Putting the information across these together, here are some notes regarding `search_type`:

- Two options: `query_then_fetch` (default), `dfs_query_then_fetch`
- `dfs_query_then_fetch` offers "more accurate scoring" by having one node in the distributed cluster bring together and merge statistics from multiple shards (indexes) that contain randomly distributed docs, and therefore varying statistics at the shard level.  The downside is that this coordination may come at a performance cost as query complexity increases.

So then, why not just settle and use `dfs_query_then_fetch`?  I believe it is due to an important note in the doc you referenced.  The statistics in shards and replicas vary due to deleted docs.

> However for practical reasons, those deleted documents are taken into account for index statistics
>
> ... then it might have index statistics that are sufficiently different from the replica (which still have plenty of deleted documents) so that scores are different too

I think as a result of subtleties such as those when it comes to shards, replicas, even `dfs_query_then_fetch` may not be sufficient in guaranteeing that you get an identical result set.  For one request, ES may decide to return results based on primary shards, and in the next request, it may decide to return results based on replicas with different statistics.

And so, you must declare your `preference`.  Preference parameter allows you to direct Elasticsearch to hit the same set of shards by passing an identical parameter value between requests.  And it indicates as much when it notes:

> The recommended way to work around this issue is to use a string that identifies the user that is logged is (a user id or session id for instance) as a preference. This ensures that all queries of a given user are always going to hit the same shards, so scores remain more consistent across queries.

However, you may have a requirement that when two users perform the same search or one user shares a url to a result set to another user, both want all users performing a single query, q, to receive an identical result set assuming not updates have been made.  What you can do is leverage the ability to provide custom string values to the `preference` parameter and perhaps hash the user query so that an identical preference value is sent for requests with the same query.  This will ensure a query for "Why is ES trolling me with different results?" by two separate users results in identical sets of results.

NB: if you pass an identical `preference` value for every request regardless of query, you defeat the purpose of distributed search.  I also don't know what you shard/replica settings are like but I believe these specific details from the docs most likely highlight / explain your observations.

Comment: Can we use some random string as a preference parameter ? is there any tts for preference parameters ? will it cause any issues if numerous preference has been used

Comment: Yes, random strings may be used, but these should probably be limited to number of active user sessions so that a single session perceives consistency - no reason to randomize with every request or should not even supply it at all.  Doubt numerous preferences should cause issues... and not sure what is meant by tts.