# Inconsistent Elasticsearch scores with async python client

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm consuming an elastic search cluster with 3 nodes and keep receiving consistent results for only a very short period of time despite having defined the `preference` parameter.

I found the following litterature and I could not really understand what am I missing:

- [Different Elasticsearch results for the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285204/different-elasticsearch-results-for-the-same-query?rq=3)
- [Different results for same query in Elasticsearch Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909205/different-results-for-same-query-in-elasticsearch-cluster)
- [Difference in results between "preference" and "search_type" on _search in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806751/difference-in-results-between-preference-and-search-type-on-search-in-elast)
- [Elasticsearch Scoring Inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70899164/elasticsearch-scoring-inconsistency)

I'm looking for recommendations on how to address this issue or aspects I might be missing as it starts to be annoying once we start using pagination.

My client is defined as following:

```
es_client = AsyncElasticsearch(
        hosts=[3 nodes],
        ...
        sniff_timeout=10,
        sniffer_timeout=60,
        sniff_on_connection_fail=True,
        max_retries=5,
        retry_on_timeout=True,
        request_timeout=30,
    )
```

and I execute my search as:

```
resp = await es.search(query=query, index=index, source=source, size=size, from_=from_, preference=preference
    )
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you provide more details? In particular, it would be helpful to see the query and inconsistent responses with explain flag set to true.